# No internet while first start - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I use Ubuntu version 20.04. Its been some days since I've been getting no internet when I start first time my laptop, on the restart (which takes astonishingly unsual time) internet works. I'd like to know how can I repair it. I'm worrying because same thing happened when I was using last Ubuntu version & one day finally internet had gone & I then re-installed new version. Can any one help me ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Sometimes I have to reboot Ubuntu twice for internet to work. Restarting just the networking service instead could work and save time but it's not really a full fix.